# Basic HTML list of videos to play using JWPlayer and CloudFront

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am trying to do a very basic test of placing a series of rows of text on a web page, each containing a hyperlink showing the tile and, once clicked, opening a separate window and autostarting playback.

I've done any number of failed tests but I'm not sure of the basics of the approach.  Should I be using OnClick=jwplayer.load(...)?  Can one use load and specify an RTMP link to a CloudFront distribution and file?

Some code:

```
<a href="#" onClick='jwplayer("mediaplayer").load({file: "rtmp://<my distribution>/cfx/st/<myfile.mp4", title: "<my title"} )'>Play</a>
```

I assume that permissions of the CloudFront distribution are ok because I am able to create a PlayList in code and envoke jwplayer allowing the user to select videos there.

But I need to be able to envoke a single video.

Comment: What does your code look like? What errors are you getting etc??

Comment: My anchor looks like this:

    <a href="#" onClick='jwplayer("mediaplayer").load({file: "rtmp://<my distribution>/cfx/st/<myfile.mp4", title: "<my title"} )'>Play</a>

Comment: The error is No playable source found.
<my distribution> and <my title> are replaced in the code by valid values.

Comment: I don't have a link yet, as I'm currently confined to a development machine.

CAN one envoke jwplayer using the load method and specifying the CloudFront distribution in this way?  I don't know that I'm even approaching this the correct way.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. Please put up a test page.